# OutOfMemory when saving imagein Richtextbox

Tags: vb.net, image, out-of-memory, richtextbox

I am using a richtextbox as a notes fields, which enable user to add image

now I get outofmemory error when saving the fields when it contains image with resolution 4800x2800,

error occurs on rtfText = Me.txtNotes.Rtf when I debug it

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in mscorlib.dll"

is there a limit to the size ? I am planning to limit the image to 1920x1080 but not sure how since it's returns OOM error before I can do anything (I think it's from richtextbox.rtf)

Would appreciate if I can get help to limit the image resolution that can be added

```
Private Function ValidateRichTextImage() As Boolean
    Dim rtfText As String
    Dim width As Integer
    Dim height As Integer


    rtfText = Me.txtNotes.Rtf

    Dim widthRegex As New Regex("picwgoal[\d]+")
    Dim heightRegex As New Regex("pichgoal[\d]+")
    Dim widthmatch = widthRegex.Match(rtfText)
    If widthmatch.success Then
        Dim swidth As String = widthmatch.ToString.Replace("picwgoal", "")
        width = Integer.Parse(swidth) / 15
    End If

    Dim heightmatch = heightRegex.Match(rtfText)
    If heightmatch.success Then
        Dim sheight As String = heightmatch.ToString.Replace("pichgoal", "")
        height = Integer.Parse(sheight) / 15
    End If

    If rtfText.Contains("picwgoal") AndAlso width = 0 AndAlso height = 0 Then
        Me.Errors.Add("P1MMO0001", , Tb.Errors.ErrorTypeType.ErrorTypeError, , )
        Return False
    End If

    If width >= height Then 'landscape
        If width > mcImageWidth OrElse height > mcImageHeight Then
            Me.Errors.Add("P1MMO0001", , Tb.Errors.ErrorTypeType.ErrorTypeError, , )
            Return False
        End If
    Else 'portrait
        If width > mcImageHeight OrElse height > mcImageWidth Then
            Me.Errors.Add("P1MMO0001", , Tb.Errors.ErrorTypeType.ErrorTypeError, , )
            Return False
        End If
    End If

    Return True
End Function
```

Comment: Show us what you're doing now.  ALWAYS show us what you're doing now.

Comment: I was trying to limit the image resolution allowed, it works for 1920, but when larger image used it throws OOM